# Determine an orthogonal coordinate system contained in the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following points in space R3: A (1,1,1), B (3,2,1) and C (2,3,2).
Determine an orthogonal coordinate system whose axes X and Y are contained in the plane formed by points A, B, and C.

Tip: The product vector between two vectors results in a vector orthogonal to the original vectors.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there any theorem or algorithm you think may help here?

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors $\vec{v_1}=A-B$ and $\vec{v_2}=B-C$ already lie on the plane passing through the points $A,B$ and $C$. The cross product of these two vectors, say $\vec{v_3}$, yields a vector orthogonal to both of them, i.e, normal to the plane defined by these two vectors. Then again, by taking the cross product of $\vec{v_3}$ with either of $\vec{v_1}$ or $\vec{v_2}$ will result in a vector orthogonal to the both and contained within the aforementioned plane. Then you can normalize (divide by their lengths) these 3 vectors to get an orthonormal basis for your coordinate system.